# the best way to store tranform.position value of instantiated object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to store the position of each object after instantiate it

```
            case 1:
                if (g_BlockCount > 0 && buildModeEnable)
                {
                    Instantiate(genericBlock, myPOS * Vector2.up, Quaternion.identity);
                    g_BlockCount -= 1;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (r_BlockCount > 0 && buildModeEnable)
                {
                    Instantiate(repelBlock, myPOS * Vector2.up, Quaternion.identity);
                    r_BlockCount -= 1;

                }
                break;
```

what is the best way to do it? I have search for them but I had found only the handful of them

Comment: Store how? For this session? In a file? Could you be more specific how exactly you need to store and access these values?

Comment: @derHugo to store every instantiate object position within one array, so I can recall it afterward.

Comment: so basically a `Dictionary<Transform, Vector2>` and then get it via `positions[someTransform]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating Lists storing Vector2 structs, you can instantiate and save the position at the same time. This is what you asked for in your question.

BUT, you could just as easily store the whole GameObject to get access to the whole transform class.

```
List<Vector2> genericBlockPositions;
List<Vector2> repelBlockPositions;

    genericBlockPositions = new List<Vector2>();
    repelBlockPositions= new List<Vector2>();
    switch ( blockType)
    {
        case 1:
            if (g_BlockCount > 0 && buildModeEnable)
            {
                genericBlockPositions.Add(Instantiate(genericBlock, myPOS * Vector2.up, Quaternion.identity).transform.localPosition);
                g_BlockCount -= 1;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (r_BlockCount > 0 && buildModeEnable)
            {
                repelBlockPositions.Add(Instantiate(repelBlock, myPOS * Vector2.up, Quaternion.identity).transform.localPosition);
                r_BlockCount -= 1;
            }
            break;
    }
```

I should point out that this is NOT the way I'd be approaching this. I'd either use either a List of Lists, in conjunction with Enum BlockType definitions, or a Dictionary of Lists.

Here's AN example:

```
public enum BlockType {
    None = 0,
    Generic = 1,
    Repel = 2
}

List<List<Transform>> transforms = new List<List<Transform>>();

switch (blockType) {
    case BlockType.Generic:
        var index = (int)BlockType.Generic;
        if ( transforms [ index ] == null ) transforms [index ] = new List<Transform>();
        transforms [ index ].Add ( Instantiate(repelBlock, myPOS * Vector2.up, Quaternion.identity).transform );
    break;
    // ... etc 
}
```

Also be aware that, because this looks to be runtime only code, you won't be able to benefit from the Unity component serialisation. You will have to do that manually. I won't go into either Binary or Json serialisation to the PersistentDataPath, because I don't think that's what you're after. But, in case it is, those are the terms you should be searching for.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean of storing it? Like saving it into a file/PlayerPrefs? You can have a singleton (you should probably research about manager classes) which will have a collection of Vector3's and because it is a singleton you could use it like: `DataManager.Instance.BlockPositions.Add(myPOS);`